# awseb cli inconsistent with AWS web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I am new to AWS. I am trying to setup AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am using cli.

I followed a youtube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhc1boyBkJw&t=317s). The problem is that at the end of tutorial I see "INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully." success message in terminal. But when I open AWS console in web browser, I see 0 instances running and no beanstalk environment setup.

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the same AWS region in the AWS web console that you are deploying your EB environment to with the CLI tool.

Comment: @MarkB thank you very much. You saved me from losing $$$$.

Comment: @MarkB it is not possible to check for each and every region, wether any instance is running or not. Is there any way to see all running instances in all the region on a single dashboard?

Comment: It is possible by writing a script that loops through each region. It is not possible via the AWS web interface.

Comment: @MarkB can you provide me that script

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service... If you want to try writing that script, and need help with a specific issue, then post that as a question here. If you are just trying to track your resource usage to avoid billing surprises you should look at the AWS billing dashboard.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/scopely-devops/skew. It can enumerate resources across regions.